# Search file with query string does not work on google drive api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Below is the code I am using to find list of files containing Volunteers.

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("Volunteers");
    System.out.println("Request size:" + request.size());
    do {
        try {
            FileList files = request.execute();
            System.out.println("Request files size:" + files.size());
            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
}
```

On execution it returns

```
[s~sakshumweb-hrd/3.368839385999923807].<stdout>: An error occurred: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 OK
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

What is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure about what you are trying to search when you want to "find list of files containing Volunteers", but you should specify from which resource of the file you want to search your query.

For example, if you want to search for files containing "Volunteers" in the title, your code should be `service.files().list().setQ("title contains 'Volunteers'");` or if you want to search both title and contents of the file to see if they contain "Volunteers", your code should look like `service.files().list().setQ("fullText contains 'Volunteers'");`
Please take closer look at [search parameters documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). It will give you better sense of how to search for files.

Comment: Thanks this now does not return any error. However, it's not able to print the files even now. Below is the code to print the result:

  List<File> files = retrieveAllFiles(service);
    System.out.println("list size is:"  + files.size());
    for(int i =0; i < files.size();i++){
     System.out.println(files.get(i).getTitle() + ":" + files.get(i).getOwners().get(0) + ":" + files.get(i).getDownloadUrl());
    }
    System.out.println("Printed");

which prints as:
[s~sakshumweb-hrd/3.368863286192052922].<stdout>: list size is:0

Comment: That means there is no file containing Volunteers in title or contents. Please specify what you mean by "find list of files containing Volunteers" and give q parameter you used.

Comment: Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("title contains 'Volunteer'");   this is the string and my drive has a file name Volunteer Information Form